# How to navigate into other screen while clicking a image in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am very to new phone i want to display four images in one line like tabbar and also if the user clicks any of the image i want to show another screen in iPhone.

can any one tell me how can i do that and also if possible please tell me in which files i have to write the code to achieve this requirement.

Comment: Your question can't be answered directly, since there is no one way to do this. Also there is not one file where you can write the code. I sugest you start with the [Your first iOS application](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html) and work your way to the [ViewController programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: I added four images now i need to give some background color for these four images like to view like a tab bar so please any one tell me how can i get background color for the entire row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

In ViewDidLoad

```
    CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(10.0f, 5.0f, 80.0f, 95.0f);

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];

[imageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[imageView.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0];
imageView.opaque = YES; // explicitly opaque for performance
[self.view addSubview:imageView];

UIButton *newbutton1 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[newbutton1 setFrame:myImageRect];
[newbutton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:newbutton1];


 //Method on Button Click
 -(void)myMethod:(id)sender {
    //Button is pressed 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make some xib file and build your UI.

You need to set other screens as IBOutlets and after click on button perform action to switch view.

You can set image background for UIButton.

Try, it isn't so big problem.

Answer (score 0):

[UIButton with images tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ReH7imbwPlc)

Is a great tutorial for creating clickable images.

Answer (score 0):

arrange 4 images manually in ur screen

eg

```
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView  alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)];

myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamedWith:@"ur image.png"];

UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                           action:@selector(showtheUI:)];

  [myImageView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer1];

  recognizer1.delegate = self;

[recognizer1 release];

[self.view addSubView:myImageView ];

}

//this method will trigger when u tapped the 1st image
-(void)showtheUI(UIImageViee *)sender{


}
```

create 2nd imageView like

```
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView  alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 10, 100, 100)]; etc
```

or use  a for loop to create 4 image Views. set frame according to the i value

Answer (score 0):

you need to create the custom table or more things to use for the creating a grid type of image

for that you need to use following things to use
TableView

- Custom UITableViewCell
- Array of images
- HJCache for asynchronous image loading.

Answer (score -1):

You can add buttons on your images and handle click events of buttons to Navigate to other screens